# Preserving user control on autopostback asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, autopostback

I have two user controls: dsucTopLeft and dsucTopRight in an aspx page. Each of the user controls has a dropdownlist to select values from.

The aspx page has a button "Save".

In the OnClickEvent of the button, I take data from those user controls (which return the values from the drop down list). I need to insert these values into database. However, these values set to 0 after the button is clicked.

How would I preserve those values?

Code:

ParentTemplate.aspx

```
<div class="leftDashboard">
    <uc:dsuc ID="dsucTopLeft" runat="server" />
</div>

<div id="rightDashboard">
    <uc:dsuc ID="dsucTopRight" runat="server" />
</div>
```

It also has a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" Text="Save Dashboard" />
```

This is the codebehind for the button:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If the mode is "CREATE", then it needs to insert the information about     dashboard and the charts it contains
        for (int i = 0; i < dsuc.Length; i++)
        {
            dsuc[i].dashboardId = dashboardId;
            if (dsuc[i].chartId != 0) //Here, the chartId remains 0
                dsuc[i].insert();
        }
    }
```

dsuc is an array. It is being populated in the following way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dsuc[0]=dsucTopLeft;
            dsuc[1]=dsucTopRight;
        }
    }
```

UserControl:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            initializeDropDownList();//It initializes the drop down list
        }
    }

public void insert()
{
    //It inserts into database
}

protected void chartDDLSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oldChartId = chartId;
        String chartTitle = chartDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
        if (chartTitle != dropDownMessage)
        {
            chartId = int.Parse(chartDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);
            //Chart user control should be retrieved from the database and drawn.
            chartTitleLabel.Text += "chart id : " + chartId.ToString() + " title: " + chartTitle;
            //chartUserControl.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The user control i.e. the class of dsuc[] changes its chartId when an item in its drop down list is selected. I printed the value, it works. But that same value becomes 0 when the button in clicked.

Comment: how are you adding the controls? could you put come code?

Comment: how are you populating `dsuc` array?

Comment: could you paste the code behind of your user control?

Comment: The question got too long. The main problem is that the chartId, which is the property of the user control is not being preserved when I click the "save" button of the aspx page in which the user control has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`from

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dsuc[0]=dsucTopLeft;
        dsuc[1]=dsucTopRight;
    }
```

If not, it will only populate it when is not post back. As a click produces a post back, you'll want that code being executed :)

Also, it is probably that your `clickp event is being called before`selectedindexchanged`. In that case, the code that sets chartId is not executed (yet) when the click event is fired. You can solve that doing this:

```
public int ChartId { get { return int.Parse(chartDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value); }}
```

and calling that property instead. Also, you can use that property in your selectedindexchanged event handler

Comment: chartId remains 0. The values of attributes of the user control are not preserved. How would I preserve them?